# Overriding/capturing user save and login action

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-authentication

This is my first time working with django. I am using django.contrib.auth (django version 3.2)

There are 2 events that I want to capture.

1. when user is activated
2. when user has logged in

The reason I want to capture these events is that I want to send out an email. I have gone through the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/) but not quite sure how to do this.

One thing that comes to my mind is to override the `save()` method, to see when user's `is_active` flag has changes. I have tried the following override class for a different model, which works fine... however since `user` is a built-in class I don't know where to put the following override?

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   super().save(*args, **kwargs)
   # send email
```

Also not sure where would be the best place to add my custom code when user has logged in.

Comment: There is no builtin function / method to activate a user, I don't see why you would need to "capture an event" since you would be writing code yourself to activate the user... As for point 2 see the [`user_logged_in` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat: Is these no way to override the save method of `user`? The benefit of override would be I could add my email code there once... because there might be multiple places which call `user.save()`